# Is there anyway to analyze a particular code (particularly if and for loops) in bash (or another language)?

Tags: bash, optimization

Talking about good coding practices. My code is getting bigger and bigger and I want to check if all my "if", and "for" loops are properly written. 
I think the proper word for that is indentation (thanks @tgo).

So I have this:

```
 if(cond1 = cond2)   
 if(cond3=cond4)
 bla
 fi
 fi
```

but I want the following:

```
if(cond1 = cond2)   
   if(cond3=cond4)
      bla
   fi    
fi
```

But for instance using Sublimetext I cannot see it like this. So repeating the question, is there any tool, software or something that can help me with this?

update: Sublime text has an option for this. (Edit-> line-> Indent) I couldn't add this to the answer.

Comment: it's "indentation". For many languages, there are tools that can auto-indent your code. My field is mainly C and C++, so I know about `indent` (a GNU utility) and `(lib)clang`, a library and compiler and static code analyzer and optimizer and… and…

Comment: Well obviously you’re supposed to write it like in the second example, not in the first. There are tools to “correct” the formatting accordingly but really, this is your job as the author.

Comment: @tgo I think it is a duplicated. But the answer there was only with VIM (which I don't like too much) but not another tools. and Indentation it is! I'll correct it. Thanks!

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Thanks! I haven't heard of that (the GNU utility) I'll check it!

Comment: @KonradRudolph I totally agree, but you learn this with time ;). And when you have thousands of careless coding lines...well then is hard to fix it by hand. Thanks =)

Comment: @Nikko Yes, I agree entirely. Sorry, I didn’t want to discourage you.

Answer (score 1):

I use `vim` for all my code editting (and I write a lot of `bash` scripts) and it has *smart indenting* that defaults to normal, ok stuff for all the languages I use.  If you have *smart indenting* turned on and copy and paste code from your first block into `vim` (properly set up with `filetype=sh`), it'll turn out like your second block.

Comment: Thank you very much, besides of VIM is there any another way to do this?

Comment: @Nikko Sorry, since `vim` solves all my code indentation needs, I've never had to think of other ways.  Why not give it a try, it runs on all platforms and it's very easy to install.

Comment: Yeah mate, I know it but I've never liked and I feel now kind of embarrassed because Sublime text (of course as any good coding sotfware) has an indentation option so I'm using it. Thanks!